# Difference between NativeQuery and SQLQuery class in Hibernate?

Tags: database, hibernate

While I was trying to upgrade a Hibernate 4.2 code, I notice that all SQLQuery class is deprecated. Eclipse is suggesting NativeQuery.
Can someone help me with understanding - what's the difference between them and how come all tutorials still suggest SQLQuery class if it's deprecated.

Thanks!